# gpg2: Where's Linus' key?

Tags: linux-kernel, gnupg, archlinux

I'm trying to build a linux kernel for my Arch install. I'd like to verify the signatures but find I can't get the keys needed to do that:

```
[joemadeus@<host>]$ gpg2 -vvv --locate-keys torvalds@kernel.org gregkh@kernel.org
gpg: using character set 'iso-8859-1'
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: key <HEX CHARS HERE> accepted as trusted key
gpg: error retrieving 'gregkh@kernel.org` via Local: No public key
gpg: error retrieving 'gregkh@kernel.org` via WKD: No data
gpg: error reading key: No data
gpg: error retrieving 'torvalds@kernel.org` via Local: No public key
gpg: error retrieving 'torvalds@kernel.org` via WKD: No data
gpg: error reading key: No data
```

Obviously these keys are there and something is wrong with the way I'm going after them. Unfortunately there's nothing here that gives me any hints, even with verbose turned on. And, searching about I find... nothing.

I do have connectivity to the outside world and can get to kernel.org via http without any trouble. In fact, that's where I found out how to get the keys: https://www.kernel.org/category/signatures.html I've tried several times over the last couple of days, so I don't think kernel.org is having problems (unless they're very long-lived ones.)

I have created a key for myself with this login on the local system. I haven't pushed it out anywhere. I don't know if any of that matters.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution comes from this post, found by a friend of mine, which answers a similar question (but with a different error message): https://askubuntu.com/a/1027703

The default gpg config on Arch does not include:

```
auto-key-locate cert,pka,dane,wkd,keyserver
```

...and I did not supply it on the command line (didn't know it existed.) Once this option was specified it found the keys.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of importing the key of Linus and Greg is by fetching it directly by fingerprint as found by your link.

Fetch Linus Torvalds key:

```
gpg --search-keys ABAF11C65A2970B130ABE3C479BE3E4300411886
```

Fetch Greg Kroah-Hartmans key:

```
gpg --search-keys 647F28654894E3BD457199BE38DBBDC86092693E
```

This approach also makes it easier to ensure you fetch the correct keys and not any key published with the email addresses.